# Not getting exact result using ul, li and a href from code behind

Tags: c#, html-lists

I am trying to make nested ul & li tags in code behind. For that I wrote preliminary code in my .aspx page

My C# code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
    tabs.Controls.Add(li);
    HtmlGenericControl anchor = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
    anchor.Attributes.Add("href", "#");
    anchor.InnerText = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();
    li.Controls.Add(anchor);
    HtmlGenericControl ul = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");
    li.Controls.Add(ul);

    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2] != null)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl ili = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
        ul.Controls.Add(ili);
        HtmlGenericControl ianchor = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
        ianchor.Attributes.Add("href","page.aspx");
        ianchor.InnerText = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();
        ili.Controls.Add(ianchor);
        HtmlGenericControl ul2 = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");
        ili.Controls.Add(ul2);

        param = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString();
        LevelControl(param);
     }

     li.Controls.Add(ul);
     tabs.Controls.Add(li);           
 }
```

When I run my project and do inspect element on my menu I see something like this

```
|page1|
   |page1|
|page2|
   |page2|
|page3|
   |page3|
```

No Nested ul tags are created inside li ?? Why ??

For example:

```
|page1|
   |page2|
      |page3|
```

What would I have to do to get the results I want?

Comment: can you show your datatable and aspx page design ?

Comment: DataSet ds = RunQuery("Select PositionCode,PositionName,Parent from Position where PositionCode = '" + param + "'");  and in design <ul class="dropdown" runat="server" id="tabs"> </ul>

Comment: and what levelcontrol method does in your code ?

Comment: private void LevelControl(string param)
        {
            DataSet ds = RunQuery("Select PositionCode,PositionName,Parent from Position where PositionCode = '" + param + "'");}

Answer (score 1):

use this code this is work,

```
    HtmlGenericControl ul = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
            HtmlGenericControl anchor = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
            anchor.Attributes.Add("href", "#");
            anchor.InnerText = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();
            li.Controls.Add(anchor);
            ul.Controls.Add(li);

            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2] != null)
            {
                HtmlGenericControl ul2 = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");
                HtmlGenericControl ili = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
                ul2.Controls.Add(ili);
                HtmlGenericControl ianchor = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
                ianchor.Attributes.Add("href", "page.aspx");
                ianchor.InnerText = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();
                ili.Controls.Add(ianchor);
                ul.Controls.Add(ul2);
                param = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString();
                LevelControl(param);
            }

        }
        tabs.Controls.Add(ul);
```

Comment: Error 2 A local variable named 'ul' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'ul', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else

Comment: check now i have changed the code use the updated code

Comment: this will not give desired output. it will retrieve records only at level 1

Comment: @SpiderCode can you check this updated code weather it will work or not

Comment: @KarthikManoharan, when i run your code. not succeed with the desired results